# Settings not changing through gsettings command

Tags: command-line, gnome, login, dconf, gsettings

I'm trying to customize my Ubuntu installation using `gsettings` but upon new changes nothing happens using the `gsettings` command.

For example I go to the terminal and I type

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.login-screen disable-user-list true
```

This should disable the user list at login screen so users have to manually input both their username and password in order to login. Upon logging out I see there has been no changes. Upon adding `sudo` to the start of the command, still nothing. I even downloaded `dconf-editor` GUI using

```
apt-get install dconf-editor
```

to see if I could change settings that way through the GUI, still nothing. Although the changes seemed to register, there was no changes to the login screen, a user list was still available upon logging in.

I then stumbled upon a RedHat guide ([here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/customizing-login-screen#disable-user-list)) that explained doing this a different way. It mentions manually creating/editing files in order to change settings. This involved creating a new profile in `/etc/dconf/profile` followed by creating a new database in `/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/00-login-screen`. I had to create several files/folders that otherwise were not here to get to this point. I then updated `dconf` using the `dconf update` command. I logged out and the changes had been made.

My question is;

Why did it work changing `gsettings` manually as opposed to simply typing in the command into the terminal? How can I make such changes with a one line command like `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.login-screen disable-user-list true`? Upon experimentation with other settings I found I can change the wallpaper using the seemingly more simpler `gsettings` command and I did not have to create files/folders and do more work. I'm not against the latter method. In fact I found it refreshing.

I'm just wondering why this happened? Why did it only work this way around?

Comment: I think it should be `gsettings set  org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true`

Comment: You have to remember that Unix/Linux is inherently a multi-user / multi-seat OS. It wouldn't really make sense for an individual's dconf settings to affect things "above" their session, such as the display manager login screen. For some insight into the database hierarchy see for example https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-overview.html

Answer (score 3):

You were changing configuration using `gsettings` for **your** user. GDM doesn't run as your user, but uses an account made for it (usually called `gdm`). That setting has to be changed for the `gdm` user.

Something like

```
# as root, or with sudo
su --shell /bin/bash --login gdm
# in gdm's shell
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list true
```